# special characters in url give "Bad Request" or "Illegal characters in path"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, escaping, uri

I'm using javascript to request a image generated by the server in real time.

The parameter is passed in the url and grabbed by MVC, and set in the "id" parameter to the controller. Like this:

```
Public Function Index(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
```

This works fine if i dont use any special characters, like "?" or quotes. To send those I have to escape or encode this content, but how should i do it?

I tried javascript `escape` or `encodeURIComponent`, but it either gives me "bad request" or "Illegal characters in path"

A sample url would be `http://localhost/Imagem/Index/Question%3F`, for "Question?"

This returns "Bad request"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies but i worked this around by using `escape` and then converting the `%` characters to something i would later in my server code change back to % and unescape myself.

In the client script:

```
myImg.src = "../../Imagem/Index/" + escape(myValue).replace(/\%/g, "_-_");
```

In the controller:

```
Public Function Index(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
    id = id.Replace("_-_", "%")
    id = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(id, System.Text.Encoding.Default())
    Return New ImageResult(CreateImage(id))
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

You may find [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) useful. As you will see there are workarounds but use at your own risk. Add this to your web.config if you are using .NET 4.0:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime 
        requestValidationMode="2.0"
        requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,&amp;,\"
        relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"
    />
    ...
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

Personally I would recommend you avoid using special characters in an url like this. You could either transform them into some other character using a mapping function or use them only in a query string parameter: `http://localhost/Imagem/Index?id=Question%3F`

Comment: i used javascript escape and then transformed '%' to something else so IIS/MVC wouldnt complain. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a image file created by sever at run time.

In above question you are trying to access a image file as Questions?

Image file or any file is not going to have any special chracter included in name so I think it's very obvious error -  *- illegal characters in path.*

Comment: It's not a file, its an image containing "Questions?" written on it, generated real time.